# Inserting into subtype table values from supertype table in oracle

Tags: oracle, insert, subtypes

I had created two object types and tables based on that types in oracle:

```
create or replace type TEMPLOYE as object(
num_emp integer,
nom_emp varchar2(40),
prenom_emp varchar2(50),
adresse_emp varchar2(200),
tel_emp varchar2(15)
) not final;
/
create or replace type TMEDECIN under TEmploye (
num_med integer,
specialite Varchar2(30)
);
/
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES OF TEMPLOYE;
CREATE TABLE MEDECINS OF TMEDECIN;
```

and I had inserted some values into EMPLOYEES like :

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
TEMPLOYE (10,'BOUCHEMLA','Elias','6, hai sidi serhane -Khemis El Khechna-Boumerdes',024873549));
```

Finally I need to insert a record into `MEDECINS` table with `num_med=10` and `specialite='Cardiologue'` and the others attributes from the parent table (`EMPLOYEES`), how to do that using `select *` statement or a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `INSERT ... SELECT`.

```
insert into
  medecins
select
  e.*,
  10,
  'Cardiologue'
from
  employees e
where
  e.num_emp = 10
;
```